# How to output string of bits as a binary file in python

Tags: python, binary, bit

I have a string of bits I would like to output as a binary file.

```
s = '10101010'
```

The string can be much longer or complex than the example above however a shorter one illustrates the point more clearly.

I want to output this so the binary representation of the new file would be 10101010 rather than the string equivalent however I have no idea how best to do this and any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: In other words, you want the file to contain a single byte of value 170? Can we assume that the string will always contain a multiple of 8 characters? If not, where should the boundaries between bytes be drawn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you'd want is to split your string to 8-bit-chunks, and then convert them to bytes individually:

```
for index in range(len(s)/8):
    substring = s[index * 8: index*8 + 8]
    byteval = int(substring, base=2)
    print chr(byteval)
```

Comment: `''.join([chr(int(s[index * 8: index*8 + 8], base=2)) for index in range(len(s)/8)])`

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: nice list comprehension; definitively faster. My code was a bit on the verbatim side to illustrate the usage of `int()` for OP.